# Apps Script: Move SELECTED rows from one sheet to the last available rows of another sheet

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

The code below is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481380/how-to-select-only-specific-columns-when-copying-data-from-one-sheet-to-another) and was originally written by user @Cooper. All it does is that it copies the values of the columns specified in the array `colA = [1,3,2,4]` from SHEET 1 and add them to SHEET 2. I want to re-write the 2 last lines of the code, so that the values coming from SHEET 1 are added to the last available rows in SHEET 2. By "2 last lines", I mean these last lines of the code:

`drng = des.getRange(1,1,drngA.length,drngA[0].length);//destination array controls size of destination range.drng.setValues(drngA);`

Any idea how to get this done?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

```
function Copy_data() 
{
  var src = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SHEET 1");
  var des = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SHEET 2");
  var srng = src.getDataRange(); 
  var srngA = srng.getValues(); 
  var drngA = [];
  var colA = [1,3,2,4];//indirect data column selection
  for (var i = 0; i < srngA.length;i++ )
  {
    var k = 0;
    drngA[i]=[];
    for(var j=0;j<srngA[i].length;j++)
    {
        drngA[i][k++] = srngA[i][colA[j]-1];
    }
    drng = des.getRange(1,1,drngA.length,drngA[0].length);//destination array controls size of destination range.
    drng.setValues(drngA);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last row of the destination Sheet and after, add it to your `getRange()`  function. The method proposed by [@soMario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70112248/14271633) will not work because it makes requests inside the loop while you update the Sheet, and this causes it to get different values every time you call `des.getLastRow()`.

The simplest solution is to take the `getLastRow()` request outside of the loop and then include it in `getRange`. **Note** that one is added to it so that it does not overwrite the last row with the `setValue()` request.

###### `Code.gs`

```js
function Copy_data() {
    ...
    var lastRow = des.getLastRow() + 1
    for (var i = 0; i < srngA.length;i++ ){
    ...
    drng = des.getRange(lastRow,1,drngA.length,drngA[0].length)
    ...
}
```

###### Documentation

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())

Comment: You are 100% right. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to hear it.